# wifidog successful autentication gives no internet access on openwrt

Tags: oauth, openwrt

I have been trying to run wifidog on openwrt.I successfully run it but it does not give me internet acesss on successful autentication.Whenever i try to browse the internet it get redirected to the captive page.How can i get internet access upon wifidog captive page successful autentication?